# How to do calculations with class table

Tags: r

How should one work with class `table`? I need to do some calculations with `table()` results and for now I unclass table and coerce it to dataframe. It is good practice or there is better (faster) approach. I have the following example:

```
x <- data.frame(a=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                b=c('a','a','b','b','a','a','b','b','a','a','b','b','a'))

t <- table(x$b,x$a)

t <- data.frame(unclass(t))

sum(log((t$X0/sum(t$X0)) / (t$X1/sum(t$X1))) * ((t$X0/sum(t$X0)) - (t$X1/sum(t$X1))))
```

Edit: I've found I can use `prop.table`, but the question is still the same:

```
t <- data.frame(unclass(prop.table(table(x$b,x$a),margin=2)))

sum(log(t$X0/t$X1) * (t$X0 - t$X1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `table` is basically an `array`, so the same methods apply:

```
x <- data.frame(a=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                b=c('a','a','b','b','a','a','b','b','a','a','b','b','a'))

probtable <- prop.table(table(x$b,x$a),margin=2)
sum(log(probtable[,"0"]/probtable[,"1"]) * (probtable[,"0"] - probtable[,"1"]))
```